# Transformations OSTN02 to OSTN15

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, fme-form, geodetic

I have a collection of points in a .CSV which are currently in OSGB36 and have been through the OSTN02 transformation.

I would like to put them through the OSTN15 transformation in bulk, using the CSV as a source.

I've read that one way to do it is OSTN02 - ETRS89  - OSTN15.

I have been struggling to find a way to do this efficiently with minimal chance for human error.  I have used Grid InQuest and Grid InQuestII but these do not give me an output in a usable format, the same was said for OS' online batch transformer.

I only have access to , ArcMap 10.2, FME up to 2016.1, QGIS  2.16.1, Python (anaconda distribution).

Comment: There was free OSTN02 Software from ESRI UK, but they have removed it from there site (dead  link now,  was vhttp://www.esriuk.com/software/arcgis/free-mapping-software/ostn02)

Comment: ArcGIS desktop the OSTN02 NTv2 transformation is called OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_7 http://communityhub.esriuk.com/geoxchange/2011/6/7/ostn02-supported-in-arcgis-desktop.html

Comment: @JGillespie, you're getting your terminology a bit mixed up... OSTN02/15 are the names of the **transformation**. This is the method used to change co-ords from one system to another. Your data will be 'in' OSGB36, which is the coordinate system.

Comment: OSTN15 support was added in ArcGIS 10.4...or maybe 10.5 so you don't have easy access in ArcGIS 10.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in contact with Dave Campanas from safe.com support. He has solved my query, so I thought i'd post the solution on here.

He suggested adding a CoordinateExtractor transformer to extract the re-projected coordinates into the X_COORD, Y_COORD, and Z_COORD attributes before writing out to the new CSV file.

Further to this, I've added an AttributeManager before my writer to help with replacing the old coordinates.

The resulting CSV shows the changes I was expecting, so I am currently happy with my results. Please see the attached screen clip.

[image: My current FMW]

Comment: you can accept you own answer (there might a time limit). glad you found a solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

In FME (2017 onwards) has the **GridInQuestIIReprojector** transformer.

[image]

https://www.safe.com/transformers/grid-in-quest-ii-reprojector/

Full Credit to Paul Michell
https://bitbucket.org/PaulFMichell/gridinquestii

+thanks to Safe for integrating this in FME

I found this solution via
https://knowledge.safe.com/idea/22549/64-bit-version-of-the-gridinquest-transformer.html

Comment: Have you been able to get this transformer to work easily ?  I've set up a geometry for it to work with, however it's not re-projecting.

Comment: It maybe a data issue/set projection, if you have issue with the transformer  contact https://www.safe.com/support/ and send a workspace/data/log file  they are very helpful and their Evangelist Mark is on this site regularly.

Comment: Yes, I'd need to see the workspace to have any idea what is happening. Best to contact the support team I think. There's a livechat option you could probably use for this issue. I'll also ping a link to this question on our internal systems, see if anyone has a bright idea.

Comment: Hi Mark, i'm still have trouble getting a result out of my FMW. Please follow the link below to the workspace i'm using along with the most recent log.   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8tFtiXQ41dZWXNrRndjNkNsSDg

Comment: @JGillespie this week is the International User Conference in Vancouver you might be better contacting support at safe for this with this question linked and cc Mark > https://www.safe.com/support/ Submit a Case>How-to and Configuration

Answer (score 1):

If your data is surveyed in with respect to the OS Net v2001 realisation of ETRS89 and then transformed into OSGB using OSTN02 then no further data changes are necessary.

If you want to use OSTN15, the correct way is:

1. Use OSTN02 to transform from OSGB E/N to OS Net v2001 realisation of ETRS89
   lat/lon
2. Helmert transformation from OS Net v2001 lat/lon to OS Net v2009 lat/lon
3. Use OSTN15 to transform from OS Net v2009 realisation of ETRS89 to OSGB E/N

The resulting coordinates from this process will be virtually identical to your source data.
**The correct answer is therefore to do nothing**. All the other answers to this question are introducing errors into your data.

See [Transformation between OS Net v2001 and v2009
realisations](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/resources/guide-coordinate-systems-great-britain.pdf#page=40)

Also see this [article](https://www.geomatics-world.co.uk/magazines/geomatics-world-july-august-2016.pdf#page=18); OSTN15 was developed to *minimise the
change in OSGB36 coordinates* due to the OS Net update, therefore pre-existing OSGB data is already valid and does not require updating.